# Complete list of actions on Twitter

Tags: twitter

How do I find a complete list of possible actions on Twitter?

Here are examples of what I mean, though to be clear, I'm not asking for a list, but how to compile the list:

- (unsure if the following are the "correct" names, but just an attempt to explain what I mean)
- tweet-received
- delete-any-type (tweet,direct-msg)
- tweet-sent
- @reply (@name starts tweet)
- @mentions (@name within tweet)
- @tweet
- retweet/unretweet
- follow/unfollow/block
- Approve/Deny Follower Requests
- favorite/unfavorite
- list-public/unlist-public
- list-private/unlist-private
- direct-msg-send
- direct-msg-receive
- Add tweet (hashtag, photo, URL)
- Edit Profile (picture, email, bio, theme, location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API more or less reflects anything you can do in the web interface, so I would say the list is here

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api